# cant use npm init, create-react-app,ng new or any thing that inits a new project

Tags: node.js

I can't create a new node project using npm init gives me an error
even create-react-app and ng new won't work

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling node yarn but the same issue:

```
$ npm init -y

npm ERR! path C:\Users\khans\OneDrive\Desktop\reactclientpanal\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\khans\OneDrive\Desktop\reactclientpanal\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-18T11_46_48_178Z-debug.log

$ create-react-app myapp
```

> C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:49
>             throw err0
>             ^
>
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:739:10)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:31:9)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:16)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:38:9)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:38:9)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:38:9)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:38:9)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:38:9)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:38:9)
>       at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\khans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:38:9)

Should init the project

Comment: did you try `sudo npm init -y`

Comment: i am on windows

Comment: Im sorry, i mean to `run as administrator` or `runs` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771525(v=ws.10) because i think that the problem is not having enough privilege ....

Comment: did ran it as administrator didnt worked

Comment: did you try to do it in anew totally empty folder ??

Comment: worked once but not again

Comment: can i ask what is your npm and node versions ?

Comment: Updated both today several times

Comment: Update its windows issue as I am able to do it in C directory and download director but for some reason not in desktop or documents directory I am using the admin account. But the program stays